# DC circuits and Measurements

Tags: electric-circuits

A potentiometer is being used to compare two resistances, the balancing length for a standard resistor R = 10.0 ohm is 58.3 CM well that for an unknown resistance X is 68.5 CM determine the value of X. What would you do if you failed to find a null point on the Potentiometer wire AB?